# Created Module: JInstaller: :Install: Cannot find Joomla XML setup file

Tags: module, installation

I am working on creating my first module.  I have been following [this tutorial](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_simple_module/Using_the_Database) and I have stopped right before this step for creating database tables.

The problem is: I enter the path to this directory in the *Install from Directory* tab of the Extension Manager.  I tried zipping all the files and uploading the zip file, and I get the same error.  It shows the following errors:

```
Warning
JInstaller: :Install: Cannot find Joomla XML setup file

Error
Path does not have a valid package.

Unable to find install package.
```

I am wondering if there is an issue with my module setup?

The `Chat` folder is set up like this:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ------- 1263 Oct 16 11:32 helper.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 -------    0 Oct 16 11:01 index.html
-rw-rw-r-- 1 -------  764 Oct 16 10:57 mod_helloworld.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ------- 1286 Oct 16 11:58 mod_helloworld.xml
drwxrwxr-x 3 ------- 4096 Oct 16 11:28 sql
drwxrwxr-x 2 ------- 4096 Oct 16 11:01 tmpl
```

Here is the `mod_helloworld.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension type="module" version="3.3.0" client="site" method="upgrade">
    <name>Hello, World!</name>
    <author>John Doe</author>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <description>A simple Hello, World! module.</description>
    <files>
        <filename>mod_helloworld.xml</filename>
        <filename module="mod_helloworld">mod_helloworld.php</filename>
        <filename>index.html</filename>
        <filename>helper.php</filename>
        <filename>tmpl/default.php</filename>
        <filename>tmpl/index.html</filename>
        <folder>sql</folder>
    </files>
    <config>
    </config>
</extension>

<install>
     <sql>
         <file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">sql/mysql/install.mysql.utf8.sql</file>
         <file driver="sqlazure" charset="utf8">sql/sqlazure/install.sqlazure.utf8.sql</file>
     </sql>
</install>

<uninstall>
     <sql>
         <file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">sql/mysql/uninstall.mysql.utf8.sql</file>
         <file driver="sqlazure" charset="utf8">sql/sqlazure/uninstall.sqlazure.utf8.sql</file>
     </sql>
</uninstall>

<update> 
    <schemas>
        <schemapath type="mysql">sql/mysql/updates</schemapath> 
    <schemapath type="sqlazure">sql/sqlazure/updates</schemapath> 
    </schemas> 
</update>
```

Joomla Version is 3.3.0

Thanks

Comment: Joomla 3.3.0? That version was released over 3 years ago. Please update to 3.8.1 asap, as you're leaving yourself and your users vulnerable.

Comment: Also, `</extension>` needs to be at the very end of your XML file

Comment: Here's the updated file code: https://pastebin.com/j7WH2tWm

Comment: @Lodder Thats all great.  Yeah I've been having a lot of trouble installing any kind of extension but fixing the XML file got me past this step, although its throwing another exception